# convergence of $\int _0^1\:\frac{\ln\left(1-x\right)}{\left(1+x\right)^2}dx$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, absolute-convergence

How do I prove convergence of $$\int _0^1\:\frac{\ln\left(1-x\right)}{\left(1+x\right)^2}dx$$ and if it's convergent, calculate the value of the integral?

I noticed that the values that the function under the integral takes will not be positive on the integration domain $(0,1)$, so I cannot use the convergence criterion with limits.

I tried proving absolute convergence but $\left|\ln\left(1-x\right)\right|\rightarrow \infty $ when $x\rightarrow 1$, so I can't use the comparison criterion either. I'm left with Abel's criterion but I've no idea how to use that, or if it will do me any good.

Comment: The integrand is not positive but its sign is constant (negative), this is what matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate the value of the integral (in case of convergence) anyway, you could just use the definition of the improper integral and see if the following limit exists:
$$\lim_{b \to 1^-} \int_0^b \frac{\ln(1-x)}{(1+x)^2} \,\mbox{d}x$$
If this limit exists, you have not only proven convergence of the improper integral, you also have its value. For the integral, proceed with integration by parts:
$$\int \frac{\ln(1-x)}{(1+x)^2} \,\mbox{d}x = -\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}-\int\frac{1}{(1-x)(1+x)}\,\mbox{d}x$$
where the last integral can be done via partial fractions. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yup, I know how to calculate the value of the integral, but most exercises ask me to prove the convergence first, before calculating it. I understand that calculating the integral and obtaining a defined value will result in convergence. However, I think it requires me to prove convergence first, before calculating.

Comment: That could be, it depends on what your teacher/book/... wants you to do. But *by definition*, the improper converges if the limit exists so I would say this is a very valid way to check convergence as well. The fact that this method gives you the value too is a nice bonus :-).

Answer (score 3):

Notice that 
$ - \frac{\ln (1-x)}{ 1+x^2} \leq -\ln (1-x)$ and prove the convergence of 
$$\int _0^1 \ln (1-x)d x$$

Comment: $ln\left(1-x\right)$ will converge, but that only proves that the negative function $-\frac{ln\left(1-x\right)}{\left(1+x\right)^2}$ will converge. Will the positive one converge as well?

Comment: Changing the sign does not influence convergence; *$\int f$ converges $\iff$ $\int -f$ converges*.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ is a non-negative and bounded function on the integration range, hence the given integral is convergent since
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\log(1-x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\log(x)\,dx = -1. \tag{1}$$
Through the substitution $x=1-e^{-t}$, the original integral equals:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{-te^{-t}}{(2-e^{-t})^2}\,dt=-\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{(n+1)t e^{-(n+1)t}}{2^{n+2}}\,dt=-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^{n+2}(n+1)}\tag{2} $$
i.e. $\color{red}{\large -\frac{\log 2}{2}}$.